Windows 7 0x7b Error when booting
I am trying to boot of a very old hdd, it is the HITACHI HTS547550A9E384 It shows up as good condition in CDI and I am trying to boot off it because it was from my old laptop. I can provide some pictures of the errors. My bios is configured with legacy boot.
I have currently 3 OS's including the windows 7 install
Here is the full config of the disks. , Windows 7 ERROR Video While Booting.
Lenovo v145 15ast u
I am trying to boot windows 7 to get some nostalgia and if it boots ill get some games and stuff off it.
Please help me so i can make this drive bootable again.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Windows doesn’t support booting from dissimilar hardware, but that’s probably not your actual problem, as that’s a different error. Most likely case is even if it was in the original hardware it would have the same error.

I see, So should I like wipe the partition of win 7 if it isnt bootable?

Somewhere in your BIOS you need to change the SATA mode from AHCI to IDE - This will get you past the 0x7B error, and might work. If you get another error keep pressing F8 once past the bios and go into safe mode.

A lenovo v145 may be too new a laptop to be able to change the SATA mode, and if your old laptop was intel processor based, it will probably not work. Buy a USB to SATA cabe and browse the old HDD that way. Start with the \Users folder.

It was intel based... I guess the drivers the conflicting. This is sad. I will get a USB to SATA (On it's way already.) to read the data.

There is no need to boot from the drive to salvage data, and good reasons not to do so: each time one attempts to boot from it, more damage is done.

Either boot the old PC from USB, CD or DVD, e.g. Hiren's BootCD USB or Ubuntu Live, mount the odl drive, and copy data

or

Put the old HDD in an external enclosure and try to read it from another machine.


I would think any attempt to read (boot) from a failing hdd would accelerate the failure of the hdd. I would clone the failing hdd then play with the clone, after making a clone of the clone, and keeping the original in the event I needed to send it off for actual repair.

It isnt failing though, I can read all the data and in CDI it tells me that the drive health is good. I am considering to wipe the win 7 partition .

I will mark this as the answer since I am getting a enclousure for the HDD.

@Sniper, getting rid of Win 7 is a good choice. If you're keeping the old PC, there are many operating systems that are being maintained, with security and other patches, such as Linux distros. If not, then you can use the drive for data storage.
